# Insulting a widow (almana) and apologizing

Tags: sources-mekorot, sin, bein-adam-lachavero

In short, I'm looking for sources from anywhere that speaks about the severity of insulting an almana and all that surrounds this topic, what the "punishment" might be, what teshuva can be done, etc.

The reason I'm asking is because of the following story that took place.

An 18 yr old boy came home one Motzei Shabbos and found that his mother had invited over a woman (who is a widow - almana) and her daughter (a yesoma - "orphan".) There had been a situation previously that the daughter had been calling this boy because she thought maybe they'd get married one day (this girl unfortunately has emotional problems, depression, etc -- of course due to the unfortunate situation that her Father passed away when she was a little girl.) The boy saw the mother and daughter were in his house and pretty much told them to "get out" in a not such nice way. They immediately left feeling completely ashamed, embarrassed, broken, etc. The mother hasn't stepped foot into the house since this incident. Not having neighbors to go to has left them even more broken -- especially since these neighbors were so inviting. The daughter said she forgives him, however the Mother is still quite upset about what happened to her and as well that her daughter was insulted (since this incident the emotional problems and depression have worsen.) In any case the right thing to do now is obviously that this boy should apologize AT LEAST to the Mother. However this is not an easy thing to convince him to do.

(The tags on this question can definitely be improved upon!)

Comment: If someone is a jerk, quoting them some wonderful vort from some sefer (or some sefer that describes a very vivid form of gehenom) really isn't likely to do much.

Comment: @Shalom The problem is the parents of the boy (the Father at least, who wasn't there) doesn't feel that his son has to apologize at all! Since this girl was "making trouble" and bothering him....So it's really for the Father who will hopefully put his son on the right path with this...

Comment: *Sh'mos* ([22:21-23](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0222.htm)): כָּל-אַלְמָנָה וְיָתוֹם, לֹא תְעַנּוּן. אִם-עַנֵּה תְעַנֶּה, אֹתוֹ--כִּי אִם-צָעֹק יִצְעַק אֵלַי, שָׁמֹעַ אֶשְׁמַע צַעֲקָתוֹ. וְחָרָה אַפִּי, וְהָרַגְתִּי אֶתְכֶם בֶּחָרֶב; וְהָיוּ נְשֵׁיכֶם אַלְמָנוֹת, וּבְנֵיכֶם יְתֹמִים. There is dispute as to whether the verses are describing repeated oppression of widows and orphans, or even an isolated act (see [*M'chilta*, ibid. 22:22](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%91)).

Comment: why should this be different than any other teshuva between two people?

Comment: I maintain that if someone's sense of the world is severely distorted, quoting them some wonderful vort you saw online is unlikely to help. But nonetheless, Sotah 21b: חסיד שוטה ... הרי אלו מבלי עולם...  היכי דמי חסיד שוטה? כגון דקא טבעה איתתא בנהרא ואמר לאו אורח ארעא לאיסתכולי בה ואצולה. "What's an example of someone so *frum*, he's a nutcase who destroys the world? If there was a woman drowning, he'd say "it's improper for me to save her because I'd have to look at her."

Comment: It's said that a young R' Yaakov Weinberg was in a chassidishe cheider when they heard a commotion outside -- a nearby building was on fire. The rebbe told his students -- "don't look! You might see women fleeing the fire! (And they might not be fully covered)!" Yaakov went home that day and told his father that he needed a new school; what they were teaching at his school wasn't Torah.

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam in [הלכות דעות פרק ו](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1206.htm) says:

> יד   חייב אדם להיזהר ביתומים ואלמנות--מפני שנפשן שפלה למאוד ורוחן נמוכה, אף על פי שהן בעלי ממון:  אפילו אלמנתו של מלך ויתומיו של מלך--מוזהרין אנו עליהן, שנאמר "כל אלמנה ויתום, לא תענון"‏
>
> טו  והיאך נוהגין עימהן--לא ידבר אליהם אלא רכות, ולא ינהוג בהן אלא מנהג כבוד; ולא יכאיב גופן בעבודה ולא ליבן בדברים, ויחוס על ממונם יותר מממון עצמו‏
>
> טז  כל המקניטן, או המכעיסן, או הכאיב ליבן, או רדה בהן, או איבד ממונם--הרי זה עובר בלא תעשה; וכל שכן המכה אותן, או המקללן.  ולאו זה, אף על פי שאין לוקין עליו, הרי עונשו מפורש בתורה, "וחרה אפי, והרגתי אתכם בחרב" ‏
>
> יז  ברית כרת להן מי שאמר והיה העולם, שכל זמן שהן צועקין מחמס--הן נענין, שנאמר "כי אם צעוק יצעק אליי, שמוע אשמע צעקתו"‏
>
> יח  במה דברים אמורים, בזמן שעינה אותם לצורך עצמו; אבל אם עינה אותם הרב כדי ללמדם תורה או אומנות, או להוליכם בדרך ישרה--הרי זה מותר.  ואף על פי כן, לא ינהוג בהם מנהג כל אדם; אלא יעשה להם הפרש, וינהלם בנחת וברחמים גדולים וכבוד, "כי ה', יריב ריבם" ([משלי כב,כג](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2822.htm#23)).  אחד יתום מאב, ואחד יתום מאם; ועד אימתיי נקראים יתומים לעניין זה--עד שלא יהיו צריכין לאדם גדול להיסמך לו לאומנם ולהיטפל בהן, אלא יהיה עושה כל צורכי עצמו לעצמו כשאר כל הגדולים.‏

All the above is based on the Psukim in Shmot ([Ch. 22 verses 21-23](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0222.htm#21)):

> כָּל-אַלְמָנָה וְיָתוֹם, לֹא תְעַנּוּן
> אִם-עַנֵּה תְעַנֶּה, אֹתוֹ--כִּי אִם-צָעֹק יִצְעַק אֵלַי, שָׁמֹעַ אֶשְׁמַע צַעֲקָתוֹ
> וְחָרָה אַפִּי, וְהָרַגְתִּי אֶתְכֶם בֶּחָרֶב; וְהָיוּ נְשֵׁיכֶם אַלְמָנוֹת, וּבְנֵיכֶם יְתֹמִים